# Row value (with ,) values to column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do this in SQL: data in column is like this need to separate them into new columns.

```
Create table #TEST4 ( NAME VARCHAR(25) ) 

INSERT INTO #TEST4
VALUES ( 'a,b,c,d,e')
,( 'ax,bde,c,ded,es')

select name  from #TEST4
```

Expecting result like this, any suggestions will be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7pVj.png)

Comment: Please don't use images for data - use formatted data.

Comment: Best practise is to list the columns your insert into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a bit of JSON in concert with a CROSS APPLY

```
Select Name1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,Name2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
      ,Name3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
      ,Name4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
 From  #TEST4 A
 Cross Apply (values ( '["'+replace(string_escape(NAME,'json'),',','","')+'"]' ) ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4
a       b       c       d
ax      bde     c       ded
```

**Update: XML Approach**

```
Select Name1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))  -- choose the proper datatype
      ,Name2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
      ,Name3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
      ,Name4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
From  #Test4 A
Cross Apply ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(NAME,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  B(xDim)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response , JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
 this is error I am getting , I believe its because of the SQL Version  mine is SQL 2014

Comment: @Manny See updated answer.  I've included an XML approach